# my tag isn't working with my if statement in my template

Tags: html, django

So I am trying to display a badge notifier on my inbox only if I have > 0 messages. For some reason, my if statement isn't working. I'm not sure if it's a syntax issue or if my logic is wrong. I am returning a count of my messages, which is displaying and working correctly. I simple want to run my if statement on that count.

**base.html/ message counter part**

```
            {% if unread_messages  > 0 %}

                <li>
                    <a ref = 'stylesheet'   href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css"     class="notification"> 
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                        <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

            {% else %}
                <li>
                    <a ref = 'stylesheet'   href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
```

**unread_messages_counter.py**

```
from django import template
from dating_app import models 

register = template.Library()

    @register.simple_tag
    def unread_messages(user):

        return user.receiver.filter(viewed=False).count()
```

Comment: How are you registering unread_messages tag in unread_messages_counter.py. Show us more on it... and edit your post with correct indentation

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane There, I posted all of that file.

Comment: Did you load ```unread_messages_counter```?

Comment: yes, like I said, it's displaying correctly, it's just not working within my if statement. Only my else is getting triggered.

Comment: Restart your server again and try

Comment: nope, still not working

Comment: `unread_messages` is a tag, it's not in your context, you can't pass it to another tag like `if`. Your `if` tag at the moment is equivalent to `{% if None > 0 %}` since there is not `unread_messages` in your context

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your custom tag with the `as` argument so that you can store the result in a variable that you can then use in your conditions

```
{% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
{% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}
{% endif %}
{{ user_unread_messages }}
```

The docs for `as` are at the bottom of [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag)

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that `user` is not defined. So, you have to include tag with context and `simple_tag` could not do so. Therefore, you have to use `inclusion_tag`(to take context i.e, `request`(in this case). [Refs_inclusion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

```
@register.inclusion_tag('pathwhere_you_rendered.html', takes_context=True)
def unread_messages(context):
    request = context['request']      // request from 
    try:
        unread_messages = request.user.receiver.filter(viewed=False).count()
    except:
        // When user is not logged in
        unread_messages=0

    return {'unread_messages':unread_messages}
```

`pathwhere_you_rendered.html` could be like, `home/base.html`

Comment: Not sure if this method would work, but the above answer is simpler, so I went with that. But thanks anyways!